# SwiftUI: how to properly use init()?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to make use of `init` to call the `fetchProducts` function in my `ViewModel` class.  When I add `init` though, I am getting the following 2 errors:

`Variable 'self.countries' used before being initialized`

and

`Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties`

The variable `countries` is binding though so there shouldn't need to be an initialized value in this view.  Am I using `init` incorrectly?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Namespace var namespace;
    @Binding var countries: [Country];
    @Binding var favLists: [Int];
    @State var searchText: String = "";

    @AppStorage("numTimeUsed") var numTimeUsed = 0;
    @Environment(\.requestReview) var requestReview
    
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel();
    
    init() {
        viewModel.fetchProducts()
    }

    var body: some View {

    }

}
```

Comment: What's with the semi colons?

Comment: Move `viewModel.fetchProducts()` to `onAppear` instead to start with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the initialiser that autocomplete gives you when you use `ContentView`…

```
ContentView(countries: Binding<[Country]>, favLists: Binding<[Int]>)
```

If you're creating your own initialiser, it will need to take those same parameters, e.g.

```
init(countries: Binding<[Country]>, favLists: Binding<[Int]>) {
    _countries = countries
    _favLists = favLists

    viewModel.fetchProducts()
}
```

Alternatively, use the default initialiser, and instead…

```
onAppear {
    viewModel.fetchProducts()
}
```